# MonoTouch - System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation fails ("Could not Load signature of [type]).

Tags: c#, wcf, mono, xamarin.ios

We have a custom JSON WCF binding that we use in our .net SDK (to support JSON similar to the WebHttpBinding). Our SDK is a PCL supporting .net 4.5, Win8, IOS, Android profile - It works in our Windows Desktop application, and Android without any problem. We are just diving into MonoTouch, and have been tracing down why our custom WCF bindings were not working correctly. We were able to identify that in our WCF class that implements the System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior interface, MonoTouch fails when trying to handle **System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation**.

The exact error is mono "Could not load the signature of (our custom type) Failed for unknown reasons."

When I configure the .csproj Linker Options to "Link SDK assemblies only" and attempt to compile, I get the error:

```
Xamarin.iOS 8.6.1 Business Edition using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk
MTOUCHTASK: error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation" reference from "System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
Task "MTouchTask" execution --
```

Looking for any kind of work around, as we need the client operation to configure the "Formatter" property when passed in via the ApplyClientBehavior method.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted this problem to Xamarin, and they confirmed that my report is a bug in Mono 3.1 - they have resolved it in Mono 4.0 but that is not out yet at the time of this writing. Hope this helps someone else out who might spend hours trying to resolve it.

Issue was the PCL library ClientOperation wouldn't work, but under the MonoTouch assmebly it was fine.  Xamarin opened a private bug, so I don't have a reference number.